# sample size from calculation exceed population size

Tags: chi-squared-test, sample-size, gpower

I calculated sample size from G*Power and got a result of 500. But my population size is just 330. What should I do?

For information, I used chi-square test for calculating sample size.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you calculated the required sample size after obtaining the sample?

Comment: If the population of interest is so small, you should be using a finite population correction

Comment: @IWS I calculated the required sample size before sampling.

Comment: @Glen_b Is G*power has this option. If it doesn't have, could you please tell me more how to do.

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do 
this in the **My Account** section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.

Comment: @avung I have no idea whether G\*power does it or not, but a sample size calculator that can't do fpc would be a weak calculator indeed. I can't tell you how to do it -- you haven't said *which* chi-squared test you're doing.

Comment: Well I have just looked through the G\*power manual. Apparently they don't know about finite populations there, at least I couldn't find anything that suggests it. You'll need more details in your question.

Comment: @Glen_b I use chi-square test of independence.

Comment: Please give all necessary details in your question. When you used the sample size calculator, was "I use chi-square test of independence." the only information it needed?

Comment: sorry for giving not enough details. I'd like to test the association of 2 qualitative variables which make 2x3 contingency table. I'd like to know how much observations I should have before doing my research. From previous research, effect size is 0.1. I input alpha=0.05 and power=0.8 with df=2. I got total sample size of 964. But my population has only 330.  

I'm not sure if this's enough details for helping me. Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps the way to proceed is to calculate what kind of power you have if you use all 330, but I'm wondering why you're doing inference if you know the entire population.